# Windows .NET Application not opening After Sudden shutdown due to power failure

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, dll, desktop-application

I am working on one VB.NET Based SCADA System. My application working fine on all my machines. When there is sudden power failure or shutdown after we start system application not opening. I am having following DLLL's AcroPDF.dll ActUtlType.dll(ActiveX Control based Mitsubishi PLC Driver) itextsharp.dll(Pdf Generator)

Please suggest me any solution to prevent above Problem.

After crash in Event Viewer found this error.

`The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.Xml.XmlException at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(System.Exception) at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(System.String, System.String[]) at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32 ByRef, Int32 ByRef, Int32 ByRef) at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText() at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent() at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read() at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Skip() at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Skip() at System.Configuration.XmlUtil.StrictSkipToNextElement(System.Configuration.ExceptionAction) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSectionsRecursive(System.Configuration.XmlUtil, System.String, Boolean, System.String, System.Configuration.OverrideModeSetting, Boolean) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSectionsRecursive(System.Configuration.XmlUtil, System.String, Boolean, System.String, System.Configuration.OverrideModeSetting, Boolean) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSections(System.Configuration.XmlUtil) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile() Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors() at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(System.Object, System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigEventArgs) Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(System.Object, System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigEventArgs) at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.OnConfigRemoved(System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigEventArgs) at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.RemoveConfigImpl(System.String, System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(System.String) at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(System.String) at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(System.String) at System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.ReadSettings(System.String, Boolean) at System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.GetPropertyValues(System.Configuration.SettingsContext, System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyCollection) at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertiesFromProvider(System.Configuration.SettingsProvider) at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(System.String) at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(System.String) at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(System.String) at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(System.String) at FX3U_PLC.My.MySettings.get_R_LOT_SIZE() at FX3U_PLC.MainNew.InitializeComponent() at FX3U_PLC.MainNew..ctor() Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException at FX3U_PLC.My.MyProject+MyForms.Create__Instance__[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.__Canon) at FX3U_PLC.My.MyProject+MyForms.get_MainNew() at FX3U_PLC.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm() at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun() at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel() at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(System.String[]) at FX3U_PLC.My.MyApplication.Main(System.String[])`

and one more error is

`Faulting application name: FX3U_PLC.exe, version: 2.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5fc89f1e Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.18362.1049, time stamp: 0xc4675baa Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x001144c2 Faulting process id: 0x2f8 Faulting application start time: 0x01d6c94de8af3c72 Faulting application path: C:\Users\This\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\YOW3KYKT.3DV\RTKA2RNL.R49\fx3u..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0000_c3d5e39f79ec6fae\FX3U_PLC.exe Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id: f31f7824-1b2f-4e6b-929b-f4c2ef65ab2b Faulting package full name:  Faulting package-relative application ID:`

Comment: Is it your own code? Run it with the debugger and see what's happening. If it's not your own code, contact the application vendor for help.

Comment: @KenWhite It's My code only. On debugging works fine. After publish and install different machine I am getting this problem. Only happening this type of problem when we switch off power while application running.

Comment: Based on the stack trace, it looks like the crash happens when it's trying to parse a config file, so I would check on the config file on the machine where it's crashing.